# @SET (SQL) in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

How to state SET @unix_four_weeks_ago = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(curdate()) - 2419200; in php file.

SQL

```
SET @unix_four_weeks_ago = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(curdate()) - 2419200;
SELECT id FROM USERS WHERE timemodified >= @unix_four_weeks_ago;
```

PHP

```
$result=$mysqli->query("SET @unix_four_weeks_ago = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(curdate()) -  2419200;SELECT id FROM USERS WHERE timemodified >= @unix_four_weeks_ago; ");
```

The query is all about getting the last 4weeks records. The query was working fine in SQL, but not giving any output when I run php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others already said, multi_query will allow you to run multiple statements in one go.  However, this query is quite convoluted and hard to read, you at least have to document the meaning of magic number `2419200`. Also, due to DST considerations, this query is not exactly correct for those time bands that contain a DST switchover event. You could also transform this query into

```
SELECT id from users where timemodified >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SUBDATE(curdate(), 28))
```

which is a bit more readable, and as proper datetime calculations are used, more correct.

Comment: fvu- The query was working, but how did you get 28. Could you explain me

Comment: Four weeks is 28 days, and SUBDATE [takes a number of days or an INTERVAL specification](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subdate) as its second parameter - I could have written `SUBDATE(curdate(), INTERVAL 28 day)` to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_query()` only permits one statement.  Although you can use `mysqli_multi_query()`, you can also rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT id
FROM (SELECT  @unix_four_weeks_ago := UNIX_TIMESTAMP(curdate()) - 2419200
     ) params CROSS JOIN
     USERS
WHERE timemodified >= @unix_four_weeks_ago;
```

This allows you to set the value directly in the statement.

Comment: Gordon Linoff - what does params indicate. Can you elaborate your answer with one example.

Comment: @CoreenStupka . . . It is just a subquery used for initializing variables.  MySQL processes the `FROM` first, so this is safe.